# User-defined function to print line when ID is entered

Tags: python, pandas, portfolio

```
df= pd.read_csv('portfolios.csv') 
df1 = df.set_index('id');df
df1
```

Hi guys, I'm not sure how to start. I have attached a picture here. Can I ask how do I define a user function, whereby I input the id, I will get the entire row?

Thanks for your help guys. The question:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for one row `DataFrame` use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with double `[]` and for `Series` only one `[]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

df1 = df.set_index('id')
print (df1)
    B  C  D  E  F
id               
1   4  7  1  5  a
2   5  8  3  3  a
3   4  9  5  6  a
4   5  4  7  9  b
5   5  2  1  2  b
6   4  3  0  4  b
```

---

```
def get_line1(x, val):
    row = x.loc[[val]]
    return row

def get_line2(x, val):
    row = x.loc[val]
    return row
```

---

```
out = get_line1(df1, 5)
print (out)
    B  C  D  E  F
id               
5   5  2  1  2  b

out = get_line2(df1, 5)
print (out)
B    5
C    2
D    1
E    2
F    b
Name: 5, dtype: object
```

Comment: hello Jez, can you give an example? thank you very much!